# Error fetching data from database and undefine index

Tags: pdo, fetch

I'm passing value 13 to processpayment.php, but the function i call does not return any value to $req_que_info.

```
<a href="processpayment.php?id=13"</a>
```

processpayment.php?id=13:

```
include("database.php");
$queue_id=$_GET['id'];
$req_que_info = $database->getQueInfo($queue_id);
$count = count($req_que_info); 
echo $req_que_info['queue_id'];
echo $count;
```

database.php:

```
function getQueInfo($queue_id){
   $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_QUEPAY." WHERE queue_id = ?";     
   $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($q);
   $stmt->execute(array($queue_id));
   $dbarray = $stmt->fetchAll();
   return $dbarray;
}
```

Comment: it seem works when i change fetchAll() to fetch() in function getQueInfo($queue_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `fetchAll` returns a group of arrays like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [queue_id] => 13
            [name] => foo
            [age] => 99
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [queue_id] => 13
            [name] => bar
            [age] => 88
        )
)
```

and `fetch` an (*single*) array like

```
Array
(
    [queue_id] => 13
    [name] => foo
    [age] => 99
)
```

try

```
echo $req_que_info[0]['queue_id'];
```

may you use

```
foreach($req_que_info as $info)
    echo $info . "<br />";
```

just see whats in the array.

```
print_r($req_que_info);
```